Two-dimensional affine quotient singularity modulo a linear element
Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$. Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $GL(2, k)$ such that $\sigma- I_2$ does not have rank $1$ for every $\sigma\in G$. Consider the invariant subring $R := k[[x, y]]^G$  which is known to be a normal local domain of Krull dimension $2$. Let $\mathfrak m$ be its maximal ideal. If $x\in \mathfrak m\setminus \mathfrak m^2$, then must $R/xR$ be reduced?

Consider the simplest case where $G$ has order two and acts by
$$
(x,y) \mapsto (-x,-y).
$$
Then
$$
R \cong k[u,v,w]/(uw - v^2)
$$
and
$$
R/uR \cong k[v,w]/(v^2)
$$
is not reduced.
